# Php bash script not support date %N or timeout command, how to fix it?

Tags: php, bash, date, timeout

I am running a bash scripts `simple.sh` from PHP page using MAPP server on Mac.

Inside `simple.sh` script I have some date and timeout commands, here part of the commands:

```
TIMEOUT=1800
CURRENT_TIME=$(date '+%s%N') 
echo "$CURRENT_TIME"
myOutput=$(timeout $TIMEOUT java -jar ../myJAVAapp.jar )
```

I test the `simple.sh` on terminal by running `./simple.sh` and that works perfect.

Now, I need to run `simple.sh` from a PHP page using the following commands:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('../scripts/simple.sh');
    $output = null;
    $return_var = null;
    $contents = escapeshellarg($contents);
    exec("bash -c $contents 2>&1", $output, $return_var);
```

However, I got these errors:

```
1654778186N: value too great for base (error token is "1654778186N")
timeout: command not found
```

It look like the bash that PHP using did not recognized the '%N' or 'timeout' commands. What should I do to fix these issues?

Comment: Likely `escapeshellarg` is causing issues. Why not just execute the shell as you did before? `exec("sh ../scripts/simple.sh")`?

Comment: I cannot run it like before. I need a php page to run it as a whole program and without `escapeshellarg` it cannot run the commands because it complicated commands the includes for and while loops.  I think it has something to do with bash version because php is using bash V3 and my terminal using V4 and I do not how to change bash version that php is using.

Comment: `var_dump($contents)` gives back what?

Comment: give me the code exactly as it in the simple.sh

Comment: I had also the same issue with `timeout ` command. When run it through the terminal it works , however when run it through php is shows error message `timeout: command not found: command not found`

Comment: With `escapeshellarg` you should have `CURRENT_TIME=$(date '\''+%s%N'\'')`. `escapeshellarg` quotes everything so you be ending up with `bash -c 'TIMEOUT=1800...` or `bash -c 'CURRENT_TIME=`, either case neither what you are saying

Comment: I found a solution: I just add to the simple.sh file this line `PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"` so the date can use the GNU date